# Add real time forex market chart in my Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, charts, trading, forex

I have a java application built with swing. And I want to add a real time forex trading chart to the app. Or how to implement trading view open source chart with java swing.

Its for my school project.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have searched on Google, please any already written code you can point me to.

I'm expecting something like AAPL chart given by tradingview

Answer (score 2):

Swing has no built-in graphing and charting package. You can use JFreeChart. Take a look at [this](https://caveofprogramming.com/java/charts-in-java-swing-with-jfreechart.html) .